# PhantomJS executes 0 of 0 Tests

Tags: angular, phantomjs, karma-runner

My question is similar to [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.038 secs / 0 secs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50523304/phantomjs-2-1-1-linux-0-0-0-executed-0-of-0-error-0-038-secs-0-secs), but I have provided additional details leading to the error.

When executing Unittests with Karma in Angular with PhantomJS we got the following error message:

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.015 secs / 0 secs)

When executing the same tests with Chrome everything works perfectly and the tests are executed.

We have to use PhantomJS.

This is our karma.conf.js.

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    failOnEmptyTestSuite: false,
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev',
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: true,
  });
};
```

Comment: there seems to be an issue on github related to this error: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/44

Comment: did you manage to solve this somehow? I don't have any special characters.